# Counts from three tables in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables:  invoices, payments, and refunds. I'd like to get a txn count by type, grouped by month/year.

I'm looking for results like:

```
Month-Year    Invoices    Payments    Refunds
01-2013        32432        534        32
02-2013        4323        789         53
```

I can get a single tables count (minus some casting) with something like:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(txndate)
    , MONTH(txndate)
    , COUNT(*)
    , "Invoice" AS type
FROM invoices
GROUP BY
    YEAR(txndate)
   , MONTH(txndate)
```

If it comes down to it, I can just make three queries (one to each table) and then consolidate my results, but I figure there's got to be a smarter way.

Each table has a TxnDate column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sqlfiddle, or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is really easier, but you could construct something like that with a bunch of `UNION`s:

```
SELECT year, month, SUM(invoice) AS invoices, SUM(payment) AS payments, SUM(refund) AS refunds
FROM (SELECT YEAR(txndate) AS year, MONTH(txndate) AS month, 
             1 AS invoice, 0 AS payment, 0 AS refund
      FROM   invoices 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT YEAR(txndate) AS year, MONTH(txndate) AS month, 
             0 AS invoice, 1 AS payment, 0 AS refund
      FROM   payments
      UNION ALL
      SELECT YEAR(txndate) AS year, MONTH(txndate) AS month, 
             0 AS invoice, 0 AS payment, 1 AS refund
      FROM   refunds) t
GROUP BY year, month
```

Comment: Eek that's ugly. I can't think of a better 1 query solution though

Comment: Hmm, what do you think about outer joining the 3 tables, and counting the non-nulls?

Comment: @Cruncher not quite sure how that would work. What would you be joining on? I don't think there's any guarantee that the date is unique in any of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, putting selects before the from

```
SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM invoices
WHERE YEAR(txndate) = YEAR(main.txndate) AND MONTH(txndate) = MONTH(main.txndate))
as invoices,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM payments
WHERE YEAR(txndate) = YEAR(main.txndate) AND MONTH(txndate) = MONTH(main.txndate))
as payments,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM refunds
WHERE YEAR(txndate) = YEAR(main.txndate) AND MONTH(txndate) = MONTH(main.txndate))
as refunds

FROM invoices as main
GROUP BY YEAR(txndate), MONTH(txndate)
```